# Remove \n using regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript string contains html table like this:

```
  <div class="nobrtable"><table class="at"><TBODY><TR><td> FY

  </TD><td> Profit Margin

  </TD><td> Asset Turnover

   </TD><td> RoA

   </TD><td> Leverage Ratio

   </TD><td> RoE

   </TD><td> Cash Conversion

   </TD><td> Cash RoE

   </TD><td> RoC

    </TD></TR><TR><td> 2002

     </TD><td> 5.1%

    </TD><td> 1.42

     </TD><td> 7.2%

      </TD><td> 127%

      </TD><td> 9.2%

      </TD><td> 163%

      </TD><td> 14.9%

      </TD><td> 16.9%

      </TD></TR>

      </TD></TR></TBODY></table></div>
```

How could I using regular expression to remove all the '\n' in the table? Otherwise it is too long.

I tried using

```
ele = ele.replace(/\n/g, ' ');
```

It will replace all the '\n' in my string. **I just want to remove all the '\n' in all the html tables.**

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean its `too long`?

Comment: It'd be really helpful if you could explain how exactly the string length is an issue and why removing `\n` (and not `\r` or `\t` or spaces) will fix it.

Comment: Imagineallthebandwidthyou'llsavebyremovingunnecessarywhitespace!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ele = ele.replace(/\s+<\/TD>/g,' </TD>')
```

/m on the regex means match multi-line which helps matching on multiple \n's in a string.

**UPDATE**

- dropped the /m modifier
- changed \s* to \s+
- introduced a whitespace character in the replacement string as browsers will render a whitespace character after your text in the TD, which you may want (though better to use no space and use CSS for padding/margins

Comment: finally, i use ele = ele.replace(/\s*<\/TD>/gim,'</td>'); /i for case insensitive.

Comment: I test it under IE 7,8,FF,Chrome and Safari. It's ok. But under IE 9, it seem not effect. Any suggestion?

Comment: Hmm...is your IE9 affected by this code also?  http://icodesnip.com/snippet/javascript/ie9-regex-bug

Comment: +1, except I would use `\s+` instead of `\s*`; if there's no whitespace before the tag, you don't need to do anything.  `\s+` only matches if there's at least one whitespace character.

Comment: Also, your description of the `/m` modifier is incorrect.  All it does is change the behavior of the `^` and `$` anchors, and you aren't using those.  `\n` is a whitespace character, so `\s` will always match it regardless of the matching mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ele = ele.replace(/\n<\/TD>/g, '</TD>');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're talking about the HTML source or the inner HTML at runtime, butyou could try trimming the inner HTML of each TD element as follows:

```
var tds=document.getElementsByTagName('td'), i;
for (i=0; i<tds.length; i++) {
  tds[i].innerHTML = tds[i].innerHTML.trim();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have original text in a variable called `html` following should work for you:

```
var m = html.match(/<table[\s\S]*<\/table>/i);
var tableWithoutNewLine = m[0].replace(/\n/g, '');
html = html.replace(/<table[\s\S]*<\/table>/i, tableWithoutNewLine);
```

After this code variable `html` will have all the new line `\n` replaced between `<table` and `</table` tags only while leaving all other new lines and spaces intact.

Comment: Thanks anubhava, you are everywhere.