# how to pass a javascript parameter with long text containing \n and \t from C#.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I have a  javascript function that has 5 parameters. I need to pass a large amount of text (it is a stack trace from C#.net code behind to the js function

Code :

```
function createDIV(CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME, APPLICATION_NAME, EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, STACK_TRACE_TEXT, EXCEPTION_OCCURANCE_STATUS) {   
    \\processing the code
}
```

When I call this function it works for all other values but if the text contains \n it fails

sample text : 
org.apache.struts.chain.commands.InvalidPathException: No action config found for the specified url.\n\tat org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractSelectAction.execute(AbstractSelectAction.java:68)\n\tat

Calling code:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    GetType(), 
    "sss", 
    "createDIV(
        '" + CLASS_NAME.ToString() + "','" + METHOD_NAME.ToString() + "','" + 
            APPLICATION_NAME.ToString() + "','" + EXCEPTION_MESSAGE.ToString() + "','" + 
            STACK_TRACE.ToString() + "');",
true);
```

I'm also unable to replace the \n with its html equivalent in C#.net. it just returns -1 for its occurance

Please help

Comment: Post the calling code.

Comment: ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "sss", "createDIV('" + 
                CLASS_NAME.ToString() + "','" +
                METHOD_NAME.ToString() + "','" +
                APPLICATION_NAME.ToString() + "','" +
                EXCEPTION_MESSAGE.ToString() + "','" +
                STACK_TRACE.ToString() +
                "');", true);

Comment: @user2133810: I added the code you posted in your comment to the question itself. You're free to edit if I made a mistake.

Comment: Show the code you're using to do the replacement. You should be able to do `STACK_TRACE = STACK_TRACE.Replace("\n", "<br>");` ... although you might have to replace `"\r\n"` if the stack trace includes CRLF line endings.

Comment: STACK_TRACE = STACK_TRACE.Replace(@"\n", "<br>");
But this still does not replace the string

Comment: Tried this too STACK_TRACE = STACK_TRACE.Replace(@"\r\n", "<br>"); did not work

Comment: Side note: please check if you caps-lock is stuck - for some reason all variable names are upper case with underscores (instead of more traditional camelCase).

Comment: :) no this is a trial page that I'm trying to display hence did it that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your C# code,for example:

```
string str = "TEXT TEXT TEXT\n, TEXT TEXT\t TEXT. TEXT TEXT\n\t TEXT TEXT.";
str = str.Replace("\n", "<br/>").Replace("\t", "<br/></br>");
```

Result:

```
**TEXT TEXT TEXT<br/>, TEXT TEXT<br/></br> TEXT. TEXT TEXT<br/><br/></br>TEXT TEXT.**
```

You can write series of replaces.

If you want to replace in javascript then use RegExp. See this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6268611/1803269)

Comment: Thanks, I think the @ before the quotes made the issue of replacing

Answer (score 0):

Try `STACK_TRACE = STACK_TRACE.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br>");`

Comment: I saw this in stackoverflow and tried it already,
STACK_TRACE = STACK_TRACE.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br>");
Does not replace

Comment: The STACK_TRACE text is queried out of DB2. It actualy has multiline text in it. When queried using an agent like DB visualizer it gives the multiline text. But when done through .net it appends the "\n\t" to each line. I'm also unable to programmaticaly remove that